# Embedded Kafka Test - The Kafka listener is not invoked

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have created a unit test to test the Kafka listener as shown below.

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092","port=909"})
class ConsumerTest {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate producer;

    @Test
    public void consumeEvents1Test() throws InterruptedException {
        producer.send("events1", "Sample message");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The Consumer is created a shown below.

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(id= "${topic1}" ,
            topics = "${topic1}",
            groupId = "${consumer.group1}", concurrency = "1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeEvents1(String message, @Headers Map<String, String> header, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        LOG.info("Message - {}", message);
        LOG.info(header.get(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) + header.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC)+String.valueOf(header.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET)));
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();


    }
}
```

The Consumer Factory and the Container Factory are created as shown below.

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootStrapServers);
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setAutoStartup(autoStart);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
   


    return factory;
}
```

The dependencies from the POM are,

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

**But, when I invoked the test case, the message is posted to the embedded Kafka, but the actual listener is not invoked. Not sure what is wrong with the test setup.**

The application.properties are given below,

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
consumer.group1=events-group1
topic1=events1
kafka.listener.autostart=true
```

Comment: can you please share the logs..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating your own `ConsumerFactory` so

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

is not being applied. The record is published before the consumer starts so you have a race condition.

You need

```java
props.put(
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
        "earliest");
```

Or you should use Boot's auto configured consumer factory.